# $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=1\implies\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty\ \&\ f(x)$ is asymptotic to the identity function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, asymptotics

> Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function s. t. $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f^\prime (x)=1$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$ and $f(x)$ is asymptotic to  the identity function $h(x)=x$.

I thought in define $f_{n}(x)=f(x+n)$ and consider $\displaystyle\int \lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x) dx$ in order to pass the limit inside the integral and have something like this: $\displaystyle\int dx=\int\lim_{x\to\infty}f^{\prime}(x)dx=\int\lim_{n\to\infty}f^{\prime}(x+n)$, but for this I must define a lower and upper limit for the integral.

I also thought in proving that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big|\frac{f(x)}{x}\Big|=1$, and for this I thought in tangent line approximation of $f$, i.e, if f is differentiable at $x=a$, then for $x$ close to $a$ we have that $f(x)\approx f(a)+f^{\prime}(a)(x-a)$, but I don´t know how to continue.

Comment: You are welcome. Now, we must ask : how would you try to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$? I would think like this : $f(x)$ may not have constant slope, but by the given condition , after some large $x$ it will always have slope very close to $1$. Use this and the mean value theorem.

Comment: What is your plan for tackling the question ?

Comment: астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг something like this: if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f^{\prime}(x)=1$, then  for each $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N(\epsilon)>0$ such that $x>N(\epsilon)\implies |f^{\prime}(x)-1|<\epsilon \iff 1-\epsilon<f^{\prime}(x)<1+\epsilon$, and integrate??

Comment: The derivative of a differentiable function need not be integrable, and that is why the mean value theorem better suits this problem.

Comment: But in this case is integrable. I should say this before but in this exercise $f$ is the integral of a differentiable function $g$, so by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f^{\prime}=g$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$:

Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f'(x)=1$, there exists $x_{0}$
such that $f'(x)>\frac{1}{2}$ whenever $x\geq x_{0}$. By mean-value
theorem, for any $x\in(x_{0},\infty)$, there exists $\xi_{x}\in(x_{0},x)$
such that $f(x)-f(x_{0})=f'(\xi_{x})(x-x_{0})$. Therefore, we have
estimation: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) & = & f(x_{0})+f'(\xi_{x})(x-x_{0})\\
 & \geq & \frac{1}{2}(x-x_{0})+ f(x_0)\\
 & \rightarrow & +\infty
\end{eqnarray*}
as $x\rightarrow+\infty$. This shows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$.

To prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$:

Observe that the limit is of $\frac{+\infty}{+\infty}$ form, so L'Hospital
rule is applicable. We have that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\\
 & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{1}\\
 & = & 1.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: One can use L'Hospital's Rule directly and show that $f(x) /x\to 1$ and from this it follows that $f(x) \to\infty $. There is no need of your first part if you plan to use L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: See comments under https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3665985/72031

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!